# jQuery select a specific option in <select> tag

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm struggling with a little script that shouldn't be that hard... I'm catching the change event of a select tag and proceed to some ajax stuff. At the end I process the response of the ajax call and under some condition I'm trying to "rollback" the user's action.+

So he's selecting an option, option is sent to server via ajax, server says "no way you can't do that", I display a little alert message telling the user he's not smart and then try to reselect the default option which is the first one, a blank.

Here's the DOM part:

```
<select class="closedStatus">
    <option data-requestid="2" value="-1">&nbsp;</option>
    <option data-requestid="2" value="3">yes</option>
</select>
```

So, I'd like to set the selected option back to the first one, with `value="-1"`.
But so far no luck... Here's my code:

```
$('.closedStatus').val('-1');
```

I found this in another post but this doesn't work for me... **Any idea why it's not working?**

**EDIT**: Actually I'm really ashamed and stupid: The problem was I had multiple `<select>` lists in my page marked with class `.closedStatus`... Of course, it didn't work that way...

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Works fine for me, can you please show the rest of the script ?

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hc9Tw/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hc9Tw/1/

Comment: you probably have another error in your script somewhere.  Check your console and post the rest of your scriptssss.

Comment: @Michael De Keyser  $('.closedStatus option').first().click();  <<<edit:initially forgot the . of the class

Comment: check updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17366809/1719246

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.8.3.js and @Rooster I tried that, still not working... meh. :(

Comment: @Michael De Keyser since it should be working and its not, it might be helpful if you made a jsfiddle for us that recreates the issue.

Comment: @Rooster, I added a jsFiddle link in question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look for the `option` element whose value = -1 and then set the `selected` property to true:

```
$('select.closedStatus').find('option[value="-1"]').prop('selected', true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc9Tw/2/)**

What you are doing (`$('.closedStatus').first().val('-1');`) won't work because that is selecting the first child of the select, which is an option, and setting the value of that option. I'm not sure this would have any effect (I don't think you can call `val('-1')` on an option element), but if it does work, it would change the value of the first option to -1 without affecting the select at all.

Comment: This should work as I tried it in a jsFiddle, but somehow it doesn't work in my project... I edited my question with some more info and a jsFiddle. Thanks for helping mate.

Comment: I finally found what was preventing this solution, as well as all others, to work. It was due to another js plugin ("chosen") that was treating select lists differently than expected.

Answer (score 1):

it will work for you

change

```
$('.closedStatus option[value=-1]').attr('selected','selected');
```

instead

```
$('.closedStatus').first().val('-1');
```

Comment: so you're getting the value of an element by passing it's value...very useful

Comment: Please see the comments that prove his code works and that there is an issue elsewhere.

Comment: This should work as I tried it in a jsFiddle, but somehow it doesn't work in my project... I edited my question with some more info and a jsFiddle. Thanks for helping mate.